# Ebean ORM - enhancing classes manually

Tags: ebean

Can I enhance interesting classes from a code or a script? I am using gradle and it seems there are no out of the box solutions. Also I am using version 10.x of EBean.

Answer (score 0):

One way this could be done in gradle:

```
   buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.ebean:ebean-agent:10.1.7'
    }
}

def ebeanOutputDir = 'build/generated-ebean'
def ebeanSyncDir = 'generated/ebean'

import io.ebean.enhance.Transformer
import io.ebean.enhance.ant.OfflineFileTransform

configurations {
    ebeangenerator
}

dependencies {
    ebeangenerator lib.ebean_querybean_generator
}

task generateQueryBeans(type: GroovyCompile) {
    source = sourceSets.main.groovy
    classpath = configurations.compile + configurations.ebeangenerator
    options.compilerArgs = [
            '-processor', 'io.ebean.querybean.generator.Processor'
    ]
    destinationDir = file(ebeanOutputDir)
}

task syncEBeanQuery(type: Sync) {
    dependsOn tasks.generateQueryBeans
    from ebeanOutputDir
    into ebeanSyncDir
    include "**/*.java"
}

compileGroovy {
    dependsOn tasks.syncEBeanQuery
}

classes.doLast {
    new OfflineFileTransform(
            new Transformer(null, ''),
            getClass().getClassLoader(),
            "$buildDir\\classes\\main")
            .process("**")
}

clean {
    delete file(ebeanSyncDir)
}


apply plugin: 'idea'

idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs += file(ebeanOutputDir)
    }
}
```

I am using GROOVY in my project hence `groovyCompile`.